# How to calculate Cohen's D across 50 points in R

Tags: r, t-test

I have the following DF:

```
structure(list(AgeGroup = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Young", 
"Old"), class = "factor"), variable = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 
10L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 
17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 
23L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 26L, 26L, 27L, 27L, 28L, 28L, 29L, 29L, 
30L, 30L, 31L, 31L, 32L, 32L, 33L, 33L, 34L, 34L, 35L, 35L, 36L, 
36L, 37L, 37L, 38L, 38L, 39L, 39L, 40L, 40L, 41L, 41L, 42L, 42L, 
43L, 43L, 44L, 44L, 45L, 45L, 46L, 46L, 47L, 47L, 48L, 48L, 49L, 
49L, 50L, 50L), .Label = c("Point.1", "Point.2", "Point.3", "Point.4", 
"Point.5", "Point.6", "Point.7", "Point.8", "Point.9", "Point.10", 
"Point.11", "Point.12", "Point.13", "Point.14", "Point.15", "Point.16", 
"Point.17", "Point.18", "Point.19", "Point.20", "Point.21", "Point.22", 
"Point.23", "Point.24", "Point.25", "Point.26", "Point.27", "Point.28", 
"Point.29", "Point.30", "Point.31", "Point.32", "Point.33", "Point.34", 
"Point.35", "Point.36", "Point.37", "Point.38", "Point.39", "Point.40", 
"Point.41", "Point.42", "Point.43", "Point.44", "Point.45", "Point.46", 
"Point.47", "Point.48", "Point.49", "Point.50"), class = "factor"), 
    value = c(0.714518666666667, 0.723876630952381, 0.728961368421053, 
    0.735228897233202, 0.701283807017544, 0.71396457312253, 0.663229964912281, 
    0.68923661660079, 0.613014666666667, 0.652671079051383, 0.547104, 
    0.602951166007905, 0.504106245614035, 0.558832648221344, 
    0.487034052631579, 0.515752438735178, 0.451825245614035, 
    0.476300007905138, 0.442370175438596, 0.441173656126482, 
    0.438668315789474, 0.435859173913043, 0.450059526315789, 
    0.434047494071146, 0.478947649122807, 0.450561841897233, 
    0.481134438596491, 0.461228027667984, 0.446763543859649, 
    0.451031316205534, 0.396206754385965, 0.406836889328063, 
    0.357049368421053, 0.368716249011858, 0.343943631578947, 
    0.368048932806324, 0.376060403508772, 0.398834193675889, 
    0.413613877192982, 0.434683889328063, 0.434964894736842, 
    0.448746023715415, 0.451208631578947, 0.450663276679842, 
    0.470569192982456, 0.473143399209486, 0.515300736842105, 
    0.502499193675889, 0.543379719298246, 0.507495533596838, 
    0.550050701754386, 0.498506288537549, 0.541725807017544, 
    0.482379664031621, 0.517293315789474, 0.458068636363636, 
    0.485205245614035, 0.423109671936759, 0.438844403508772, 
    0.385925747035573, 0.39522349122807, 0.362403612648221, 0.374209192982456, 
    0.350889750988142, 0.354036315789474, 0.336213118577075, 
    0.340668122807018, 0.327800648221344, 0.326388666666667, 
    0.322577146245059, 0.328114842105263, 0.319440624505929, 
    0.342721666666667, 0.323974818181818, 0.357620473684211, 
    0.335501339920949, 0.372856842105263, 0.343831292490119, 
    0.377362315789474, 0.361571442687747, 0.393890736842105, 
    0.377489727272727, 0.419330684210526, 0.38274228458498, 0.419797666666667, 
    0.387899881422925, 0.423127684210526, 0.385955055335968, 
    0.42140750877193, 0.377730351778656, 0.403711631578947, 0.366319122529644, 
    0.390753140350877, 0.355189754940711, 0.373226596491228, 
    0.347452173913044, 0.348689877192982, 0.340376324110672, 
    0.329466947368421, 0.344867375494071)), row.names = c(NA, 
-100L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

which a subset looks like:

```
 A tibble: 100 x 3
   AgeGroup variable value
   <fct>    <fct>    <dbl>
 1 Young    Point.1  0.715
 2 Old      Point.1  0.724
 3 Young    Point.2  0.729
 4 Old      Point.2  0.735
 5 Young    Point.3  0.701
 6 Old      Point.3  0.714
 7 Young    Point.4  0.663
 8 Old      Point.4  0.689
 9 Young    Point.5  0.613
10 Old      Point.5  0.653
```

I have an output using:

```
Cho_D <- DF %>% 
    rstatix::cohens_d(value ~ variable, var.equal = TRUE)
```

But this provides me with a lot of unnecessary calculations like Point.1 and Point.3, Point.1 and Point.4, etc.

I would like to calculate Cohen's D for each successive points. So for example:

`Point.1:Point.2`, `Point.2:Point.3`, etc. The end goal is to plot `D` values on the Y-axis and Points 1 through 50 on the X-axis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could `nest` the 'value', get the `lead` of the `list` column, and apply `cohen.d` by looping over the two `list`

```
library(dplyr)
library(effsize)
library(purrr)
out <- DF %>%
     select(-AgeGroup) %>%
     nest(data = value) %>%
     mutate(across(everything(), lead, .names = "{.col}_lead")) %>% 
     slice(-n()) %>% 
     mutate(cohen_d = map2_dbl(data, data_lead, 
           ~ cohen.d(.x$value, .y$value)$estimate))
```

-output

```
head(out, 2)
# A tibble: 2 x 5
  variable data             variable_lead data_lead        cohen_d
  <fct>    <list>           <fct>         <list>             <dbl>
1 Point.1  <tibble [2 × 1]> Point.2       <tibble [2 × 1]>   -2.29
2 Point.2  <tibble [2 × 1]> Point.3       <tibble [2 × 1]>    3.46
```

comparing with OP's `filter`ed output

```
Cho_D %>%
     slice(seq(1, n(), by = 49)) %>%  
     slice_head(n = 2)
# A tibble: 2 x 7
#  .y.   group1  group2  effsize    n1    n2 magnitude
#  <chr> <chr>   <chr>     <dbl> <int> <int> <ord>    
#1 value Point.1 Point.2   -2.29     2     2 large    
#2 value Point.2 Point.3    3.46     2     2 large
```

---

#### Benchmarks

With the number of comparisons reduced, the timings are below

```
system.time({Cho_D <- DF %>% 
     rstatix::cohens_d(value ~ variable, var.equal = TRUE)
 
 })
#   user  system elapsed 
# 16.316   0.060  16.330 

system.time({out <- DF %>%
      select(-AgeGroup) %>%
      nest(data = value) %>%
      mutate(across(everything(), lead, .names = "{.col}_lead")) %>% 
      slice(-n()) %>% 
      mutate(cohen_d = map2_dbl(data, data_lead, 
            ~ cohen.d(.x$value, .y$value)$estimate))})
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.031   0.005   0.037
```

Answer (score 3):

In base R you can accomplish the same using `embed` + `apply`:

```
L <- split(DF$value, DF$variable)
mat <- embed(names(L), 2)[,2:1]
res <- apply(mat, 1, function(x) rstatix::cohens_d(stack(L[x]), values~ind))
do.call(rbind, res)
A tibble: 49 x 7
   .y.    group1   group2   effsize    n1    n2 magnitude
   <chr>  <chr>    <chr>      <dbl> <int> <int> <ord>    
 1 values Point.1  Point.2   -2.29      2     2 large    
 2 values Point.2  Point.3    3.46      2     2 large    
 3 values Point.3  Point.4    2.17      2     2 large    
 4 values Point.4  Point.5    1.83      2     2 large    
 5 values Point.5  Point.6    1.69      2     2 large    
 6 values Point.6  Point.7    1.11      2     2 large    
 7 values Point.7  Point.8    0.973     2     2 large    
 8 values Point.8  Point.9    1.98      2     2 large    
 9 values Point.9  Point.10   1.82      2     2 large    
10 values Point.10 Point.11   2.95      2     2 large    
# ... with 39 more rows
```

if you can use the `effsize::cohen.d` then this function will be faster than all the options given so far:

```
my_cohen <- function(data){
  L <- split(data$value, data$variable)
  mat <- embed(names(L), 2)
  res <- apply(mat, 1, function(x) 
             effsize::cohen.d(L[[x[2]]], L[[x[1]]])$estimate)
  data.frame(mat, res)
}
my_cohen(DF)
         X1       X2          res
1   Point.2  Point.1  -2.29025540
2   Point.3  Point.2   3.45998958
3   Point.4  Point.3   2.16986489
4   Point.5  Point.4   1.82991671
5   Point.6  Point.5   1.68816593
6   Point.7  Point.6   1.11414226
```